# Can all music and playlists/ratings be transferred back from an iPod Touch to a PC?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, windows, music, data-transfer

How can I get my songs from my iPod Touch to my PC?

Some of the songs were purchased through iTunes, and others were ripped from CDs.

This is what happened:

1. The iPod Touch was set up to sync with my PC via iTunes, so my PC had all of the music on it.
2. The PC got infected with viruses and the computer needed to be formatted.
3. The music is now only on the iPod Touch and not on the PC.

Is there any way I can get my songs back to the PC from my iPod Touch (or iPad or iPhone since they all run iOS)?

Comment: possible duplicate, perhaps merge? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/how-can-i-transfer-non-paid-music-from-my-ipod-back-to-my-pc

Answer (score 3):

Try [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/):

> **Change** 
>   Add and remove music, videos, playlists and artwork on your
>   iPod.
>
> **Backup** 
>   Backup all those tracks you just can't lose onto your computer.
>   Import them automatically into your
>   iTunes library.
>
> **Share** 
>   SharePod can run straight from the iPod itself, so you can use
>   it at work, school, home - wherever
>   you and your iPod are.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that is great!

Comment: @Rabskatran Whoops, I thought I had accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

On windows, the software I used to recommend was [TouchCopy](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/index.php), but their advertising efforts seem to have turned me off their product.

On mac, the software I'd most highly recommend is [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/).

PhoneView is the well supported, a good value for my needs, as well as very full featured.

Comment: Just for completion: they're both not free ;)

Comment: I wish iTunes Match could be started from a device in this case - perhaps for an additional fee since Apple would need to "loan" you server space to process all the files and iTunes in the cloud downloads / write new software to merge things without iTunes on your Mac/PC.

Answer (score 2):

### Software to Recover Music from an iPod on Windows

- [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/)
- [MusicRescue](http://www.kennettnet.co.uk/products/musicrescue/)

Comment: Hey Senseful, Let me know how this worked out

Answer (score 2):

Just click "Transfer Purchases". Then, all your Apps, Music and Video Purchased from iTunes will sync.

NOTE: Music, Video not purchased from iTunes will not be transfered. But you can try [**iPod to computer**](http://www.ipodtocomputercopy.com/iphoneconverter/transfer-files-from-iphone-to-computer.html) transfer program.

With this software, you can back up and restore all of your iPhone content to computer, including your favorite songs, books, videos, photos, play lists and more.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this will bring back the music that Apple sold - but without playlists, ratings, etc...