# How can I transfer non-paid music from my iPod back to my PC?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, windows, music, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring music from iPod Touch to PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/transferring-music-from-ipod-touch-to-pc)

I have some music ripped from my own CDs on my iPod Touch. Recently, I lost those CDs (well, I still have one but it's too damaged to use). I also recently have a new PC, so the only copy of the music is on my iPod.

When I try to sync, I get told that 'do you wish to transfer your paid content' from iTunes. I have done this, but I don't want to sync in case I lose the music I ripped.

I tried going into the iPod via the Windows Explorer thing, but I cannot find my music files.

Are these lost, if I sync again?

Summary: Can I get music I ripped myself transferred from my iPod to iTunes?