# Can the playlists and ratings be recovered from iOS devices when an iTunes library is lost?

Tags: itunes, ipad, windows

I recently had to do a complete reinstall of my C: drive due to a catastrophic hardware failure. Unfortunately, the iTunes database and play lists and play counts were lost with no backup.

Fortunately, my iTunes media files were on D:, so I can re-import those songs and movies, but my playlists and other sync settings were lost.

Both my iPad and iPhone still have their synced playlists, but if I try to resync them - iTunes wants to erase them. I want to keep the the ratings and play count of 4000+ songs. My ratings and play counts feed into smart playlists to determine what goes into the limited space on my mobile devices.

Is there a way to get iTunes to read and/or respect/not erase the ratings and play count from a device it has yet to sync to?

What's the least amount of work I can do to recover this data from my iOS devices?

Comment: since you have your music at D: - is there any chance that iTunes has saved its library information at D: too? The file is called **iTunes Library.itl** or maybe there as a folder called **Previous iTunes Librarys**

Comment: No, it was in C: somewhere under My Documents

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/how-can-i-transfer-non-paid-music-from-my-ipod-back-to-my-pc and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/transferring-music-from-ipod-touch-to-pc

Answer (score 1):

On Windows I used [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com) for this some years ago

> SharePod is easy to use and works! Heres some of the main features:
>
> - Add & remove music and videos from your iPod
> - Add, remove and edit playlists
> - Add & remove album art
> - View and backup photos
> - Copy music, videos and playlists from your iPod to PC
> - Import music/videos into your iTunes library, including playlists and ratings
> - Tag editing
> - Drag n' drop to and from Explorer
> - Simple, clean interface
> - Quick to load and use with no unnessary complicated features
> - Support for iPhone and iTouch
>
> And whats more, SharePod is completely free! SharePod was designed from the start to be lightweight, quick and responsive, it has all (well hopefully most...!) of the features you need and none of the features you dont.

Comment: Does this work when you don't transfer back the songs - just the playlists? If not - does it eliminate duplication in the library should those songs exist?

Comment: It doesn't, in fact -- I tried to start it and all it tried to do was dump the contents of my iPad's music library onto my PC. I don't know if it intended to dump my playlists afterwards because I didn't intend to wait for 4000+ songs to be transfered over USB.