# Why are my songs on my iPhone, but they aren't downloaded?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, music

I'm trying to download some songs onto my iPhone (5S, iOS 7), but they are just grey with this little broken circle next to them. Can anyone explain what's going on? I have space on my phone, and when I don't, my computer tells me, but here the songs are just kind of there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The circle means the song exists on the device but does not exist in your current iTunes library. You need to either import them again from CD into your library or [transfer them from your device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/can-all-music-and-playlists-ratings-be-transferred-back-from-an-ipod-touch-to-a).